# SQL Server : returning sum value from inner select over rownum

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm on this site every day, but I've never posted before. I'm having the hardest time understanding why my query is taking so long.

Because SQL Server doesn't support returning a range of rows, we've had to get pretty fancy, so we're using a

```
SELECT FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() AS rownum...) 
WHERE rownum BETWEEN foo AND bar]
```

statement.

The inner select returns ~13,000 rows in < 1 second (run separately). One of the columns returned is a `SUM()` from a joined table.

The outer select takes approximately 14 seconds to return the inner select values with a range of 500 - 1000. However, if I comment out the returned SUM, it takes < 1 second - which is what I would expect.

My question is, why does just the act of returning that SUM in the outer query take so long?

Examples below

Example full query (~14 seconds):

```
SELECT yadayada, number
FROM (SELECT yadayada, SUM(innerNum) AS number, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY yadayada DESC) AS rownum
      FROM table1
      JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
      GROUP BY yadayada)
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 500 AND 1000
```

Example inner query (< 1 second):

```
SELECT yadayada, SUM(innerNum) AS number, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY yadayada DESC) AS rownum
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY yadayada
```

Example full query w/o returned SUM (< 1 second):

```
SELECT yadayada --, number (commented out, still returned in inner query)
FROM (SELECT yadayada, SUM(innerNum) AS number, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY yadayada DESC) AS rownum
      FROM table1
      JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
      GROUP BY yadayada)
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 500 AND 1000
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` does not works with out `OVER ( [ PARTITION BY ` clause! This will raise `Incorrect syntax near 'row_number', expected 'OVER'.`

Comment: Yes - I know.  We have that in the query - it's obviously running.  This was just an example, but I'll try to update it now for consistency.  - okay, I updated the examples to include the OVER statement

Comment: All three queries are wrong. You can not include `yadayada` into select clause without include it on group by clause.

Comment: Thank you, danihp, I've edited the examples again.  But that still doesn't help me.  I'm looking for sql theory help.  Why does the actual query run so slowly, when just commenting out that little bit runs as I would expect?

Comment: I know. But is hard to believe bizarre behavior reading syntax error samples. Sorry.

Comment: The simple answer is that the queries perform differently because they have different execution plans. Have you compared the plans for the two versions of the query?

Comment: Honestly, not until just now.  I'm not a SQL guy and didn't even know about it until a few days ago.  

Okay - just did that, and now I'm understand just a little more.  The query without the returned SUM looks like it turns the inner join (in the inner select), into a right outer join.  I thought that was interesting, so I did the same thing myself, with the returned SUM, and it returned all records in < 1 second - what I would expect. 

Why is a RIGHT OUTER JOIN working when an INNER JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN does not?  We're using INNER JOINs because I thought it more proper.

Comment: looking at your requirements,I dont think left or right outer joins will work.As you are looking for common ids with sum(number) in the inner query.

Comment: Sorry - it was a bad example, and written in a hurry.  In my case, all types of joins will return what I want, because I am certain that there will always be matching values in both tables.  I will use a RIGHT OUTER JOIN because it works quickly, but it seems to me that an INNER JOIN is more proper.  I don't understand why a RIGHT OUTER JOIN is faster, though.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will hazard two guesses, which might explain the problem.

First, when you are measuring the inner subquery, are you measuring the time until the first row appears or the time until the entire result set appears?  My guess is that you are looknig at the first row.

My second guess is that you have an index on yadayada and id.  This means that the subquery can all be satisfied using indexes only.  When you include the additional column innerNum, the query engine actually has to read in the pages from one of the tables.

So, the overhead for the entire query is a combination of two things:

- The need to return the full result set
- The need to access pages in th original table

I might be totally off, but this might give you some ideas on what could be causing the problem.two

Comment: Actually, I'm waiting for the entire result set to appear with all my measurements.  I know we have indexes on the tables, but I don't know which columns are indexed - or even how to check.

Comment: just copy the table name into query analyzer  and select that table name and then press Alt+F1

Comment: Thanks for the tip, guys.  I don't know exactly what I'm looking at with the F1 result set - I need to spend more time on it, but I'll have to come back to it later.  For now I'll mark this one answered.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just try this:

;WITH CTE as 
(
SELECT yadayada, SUM(innerNum) AS number, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY yadayada DESC) AS rownum
      FROM table1
      JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
      GROUP BY yadayada
)

select yadayada, number from CTE where rownum between 500 and 1000
```

Comment: Interesting... I'm not familiar with common table expressions - I'll have to read up.  However, this still presents the same problems.  Using this method, LEFT OUTER JOIN takes 11 seconds, INNER JOIN takes 29 seconds, and RIGHT OUTER JOIN takes < 1 second.

Comment: Hey did you check indexes on these tables?